# android searchView hava one issue

Tags: android, listview, filter, searchview

I have a `ListView`. On the `ListView` I have `SearchView` which filter item from the list.its work fine but problem is this when I click on `SearchView` the title `TextView` is no hidden . anyone know how to hide the `TextView` when I click on `SearchView`.

The example is below:

[image]

In the picture I want to hide the TextView Food Calories when i click on SearchView.

This is my code of `SearchView` and `TextView`:

```
<SearchView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Food Calories"
    android:id="@+id/tex"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

This is Activity code:

```
public class DataListActivity extends Activity  {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_list_layout);

        SearchView sear = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        sear.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;


            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                listDataAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;

            }

        });}
```

Comment: what is the use of textview there?

Comment: textview is used for title bar

Comment: Is it Actionbar title?

Comment: no i hide title bar . and make it with image and put textview on it for title